# How to print dereferenced value of field without explicitly specifying that field golang

Tags: pointers, go, thrift

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type outer struct {
    in *int
}

func main() {
    i := 4
    o := outer{&i}
    fmt.Printf("%+v", o)
}
```

I'd like to see {in:4} at the end of this, not {in:0x......}, i.e. pretty print the data structure.

I'd like to accomplish this in a similar manner to the code posted (e.g. with a fmt shortcut similar to %+v or an analogous solution).

This is for autogenerated code from a required field of a thrift struct.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: `&i` returns the address of (or reference to) `i`, not the value. (In other words, it *references* `i`.) So, that address is what is stored in `o`. In order to get to the actual value, you need to *dereference* the reference stored in `o`.

Comment: I think there are many libraries dedicate to that, one of them being https://godoc.org/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew

Answer (score -1):

When you use `&i` it *does not* dereference `i`. Rather it *references* `i`, which means that it copies the address of `i` into `o`. See the documentation for the [Address operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators).

From what I gather, you should be able to use `*o` to *dereference* the pointer; in other words, go from the address back to the original variable.

> For an operand x of pointer type *T, the pointer indirection *x denotes the variable of type T pointed to by x. If x is nil, an attempt to evaluate *x will cause a run-time panic.

Comment: yeah, I'm just wondering if there's a fmt shortcut (similar to %+v) that will dereference pointer fields implicitly rather than having to explicitly specify each field.
you can imagine for a struct with many fields, %+v is nice because it provides the logic of looping through the entire struct without explicitly specifying each field. I want to retain that functionality while showing values instead of pointers

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with golang to answer that. But, FWIW, the mistake you've made in your verbiage (reference versus de-reference) is very common among C programmers, as well. It's quite useful to know the difference, as that precisely explains what's happening in your example.

Comment: BTW, if you want to ask about `%+v` instead, why not ask a separate question?

Comment: I think it is not about what to store in the value, but about how to print (or, pretty-print) a already stored and fixed data structure.

Comment: @leafbebop I addressed that (dereference `o`); as well as the confusion of what is actually stored in the value (that is, why de-referencing `o` is necessary).

Comment: @leafbebop that's exactly it

Comment: @jpaugh Yes I understand your answer's contents as well as its purpose, and that is why I think you got the *question* wrong.

Comment: @leafbebop. Perhaps. IMO, the OP asked a different question than what he needed an answer for.

Comment: @jpaugh thanks for your help - i do know that de-referencing o is necessary, i'm just wondering if there's a fmt shortcut (or some analogous solution) that will do that implicitly without having to explicitly access that field

Comment: @ryebread You've asked me that. I said I did not know. I also suggested asking another question. But perhaps editing your question to include that detail will help others answer it.

Comment: @ryebread in short, simply using package `fmt` and not write extra code like custom `Stringer`, it is impossible to do the pretty-print, reasons are stated in this answer and I think you are aware of that. However, it can be done by some third-party pretty-print libraries, if you search on godoc.org with the keyword "pretty".